# Spring Reactive Security | How to implement a reactive PermissionEvaluator

Tags: spring-security, spring-webflux

Assuming we got an annotated rest controller method with:

```
@PreAuthorize("hasPermission(#username, 'USER_PROFILE', 'WRITE')")
```

In Spring MVC we would implement a `PermissionEvaluator` to implement the authorization hidden behind the following method signature

```
boolean hasPermission(
  Authentication authentication, 
  Serializable targetId, 
  String targetType,
  Object permission
)
```

This still seems to work when using Spring WebFlux as long as you do not need to call a reactive service/method inside of the hasPermission method, which I guess is rarely the case since you would typically like to use the reactive interface for your database layer as well. If you would call a reactive service inside this method anyway you would need to call `block()` on some `Mono` at some time and thereby run into trouble since you are called from within a reactive pipeline.

In the tutorial from [Josh Long](https://spring.io/blog/2017/10/04/spring-tips-reactive-spring-security) about Security with Spring WebFlux he explains how to implement authorization directly on the `SecurityWebFilterchain` using path matchers by providing custom `ReactiveAuthorizationManager`s. But there is no explanation of how to use the `PreAuthorize` annotation in Spring WebFlux.

I was expecting to implement some `ReactivePermissionEvaluator`

```
Mono<Boolean> hasPermission(
  Authentication authentication, 
  Serializable targetId, 
  String targetType,
  Object permission
)
```

that would allow using reactive services in the implementation as well but I wasn't able to find any implementation of the `ReactiveAuthorizationManager` that would scan for the `PreAuthorize` annotation and dispatch the evalutation to a reactive `PermissionEvaluator` nor does the `ReactivePermissionEvaluator` interface exist.

So finally the question is, *how to implement a reactive `PermissionEvaluator` that allows calling a reactive service, e.g. to query the database for the autorization information without blocking?*

Answer (score 2):

Sadly... this is not yet supported by Spring Security in https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-security/issues/5046

Answer (score 2):

Here is how you should do it. Just get DefaultMethodSecurityExpressionHandler bean from applicationContext and explicitly replace permissionsEvaluator.

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebFluxSecurity
@EnableReactiveMethodSecurity
public class SecurityConfiguration {
@Autowire
private ApplicationContext applicationContext;

    @Bean
    @DependsOn({"methodSecurityExpressionHandler"})
    public SecurityWebFilterChain springSecurityFilterChain(
            ServerHttpSecurity http) {
        DefaultMethodSecurityExpressionHandler defaultWebSecurityExpressionHandler = this.applicationContext.getBean(DefaultMethodSecurityExpressionHandler.class);
        defaultWebSecurityExpressionHandler.setPermissionEvaluator(permissionEvaluator());
        return http.csrf().disable()
                .httpBasic().disable()
                .formLogin().disable()
                .logout().disable()
                .securityContextRepository(NoOpServerSecurityContextRepository.getInstance())
                .addFilterAt(tokenAuthenticationFilter(), SecurityWebFiltersOrder.AUTHENTICATION)
                .authorizeExchange()
                .anyExchange().authenticated()
                .and().build();

    }

   PermissionEvaluator permissionEvaluator() {
    return new PermissionEvaluator() {
        @Override
        public boolean hasPermission(Authentication authentication, Object targetDomainObject, Object permission) {
            //Custom logic to evaluate @PreAuthorize("hasPermission('123', '123')")
            return false;
        }

        @Override
        public boolean hasPermission(Authentication authentication, Serializable targetId, String targetType, Object permission) {
            //Custom logic to evaluate @PreAuthorize("hasPermission('123', '123','123')")
            return false;
        }
    };
}
```

Comment: Please be aware that the `PermissionEvaluator` interface is not non-blocking (since it does not return a publisher). That means that you should not make blocking-calls (like calls to external services or database) within the methods of the `PermissionEvaluator`. See also: https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-security/issues/5046#issuecomment-427045308